# AWS Dynamo DB change notification on android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-dynamodb

I have implemented AWS dynamo db service as a backed for an android application.I have stored data from dynamo db in local sqlite database at the very first time.

Now I want to know if there is some mechanism AWS service gives so that I can get notification whenever any changes occur in dynamo db so that I can refresh my local database as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB has a nice feature called streams. When a data got changed it delivers old and/or new image to DynamoDB Stream which can be triggered to Lambda. You can then pick up those events and create your mobile notification with Amazon SNS or any other mode you deliver your notifications to update your Android app database.

**More on DyamoDBStreams:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Hope it helps.